# Visual Studio Jump to yellow arrow (debug pointer)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

When I am debugging my code, sometimes I need to look at another method or class. 
When I want to turn back to yellow arrow, I have to navigate between files and search the yellow arrow. I can use Step Over (F10), but I don't want to do that. I need the current status. Is there an easy way to jump to yellow arrow?

Comment: You can use ctrl+_ to move one step back , using it you can go back to the yellow arrow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Visual Studio, the command is `Debug.ShowNextStatement` and it's bound to `Alt+Num *` by default if you're using the "Visual C#" settings.  Of course, you can bind it to just about anything else you want by going to `Tools > Options... > Environment / Keyboard`.

Answer (score 4):

The yellow arrow marks the current point of execution.

There are several ways to return to this point in the editor. Perhaps the simplest is to double click on the top of the current execution stack.

Where multiple threads are involved you can double click on a thread in the threads tool window to return to the point of execution for that thread.